# Inserting Dataset into DataTable

Tags: c#, sql, datatable, dataset

I'm stuck at the moment with the problem below. I'll try and explain it as best as I can but let me know if you need more clarification. I've put some things in a google spreadsheet to help with the explanation, link below.

https://spreadsheets.google.com/ccc?key=0An70K3Q_IiWAdGpfV2YzNFQ4aTYxTWIxSUd5azVMWEE&hl=en&authkey=CMO898QP

Spreadsheet:
MainTable = C# Application DataTable
Data = SQL Results from an SQL Query (Dataset)

The data spreadsheet needs to be translated/converted into the format specified in the MainTable spreadsheet.

Each rowid is there because they relate to something unique. So for example. If we assume rowid 1 is for "Total sales for this month", you can see in the Data spreadsheet that cell C2 needs to go to cell E2 on the MainTable spreadsheet.

If we assume rowid 2 is for "stock on the shelf", you can see in the Data spreadsheet that cell D3 needs to go to cell F3 on the MainTable spreadsheet.

... and so on. I first approached it with the code below but that's not going to work because the prodcode is not unique in my dataset. I'd create another dataset or list but then I'm unsure of where to go from there. Am I looking at it wrong?

```
foreach (DataRow dsrow in dsproduct.Tables["loadUniqueProducts"].Rows)
        {
            string prodcode = Convert.ToString(dsrow["prodcode"]);

            for (int i = 1; i <= 14; i++)
            {
                row = table.NewRow();
                row["rowid"] = i;
                row["prodcode"] = prodcode;
                table.Rows.Add(row);
            }
        }
```

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a confusing question; DataSets, DataTables, and spreadsheets are all different things. Is `loadUniqueProducts` the `Data` table from your spreadsheet? That's a DataTable, not a DataSet.

Spreadsheets are ordered and have empty rows, and are more similar to a C# Array than a DataTable; DataTables should not have empty rows.

`rowid` is a really bad name for a DataColumn, it's typically used to refer to the sequential row ID from the database. `prodcode` is not described anywhere, is that the number after your "PRODUCT" data?

Why are you adding 14 blank rows? You should only add rows that have data to a DataTable. Then you do it again for each row in `loadUniqueProducts`. Massive duplication of data.

I'm assuming what you want to do is step through each row in `loadUniqueProducts` and find the matching row in `MainTable`. If this row does not already exist, create it. Then figure out which MainTable column the "uniqueProducts" has values for, and copy them. Does that sound right?

Here is some sample code doing that for Total Sales (RowID = 1). I have not done this for Stock on Shelves, or any other columns, but this should give you the idea:

```
foreach (DataRow r in dsproduct.Tables["loadUniqueProducts"].Rows)
{
    int productID = r.Field<System.Int32>("ProductID");
    string productExpression = "ProductID=" + productID.ToString();
    string salesExpression = productExpression + " AND RowID=1";

    int? monthSales = r.Field<System.Int32?>("MonthSales");
    if ((monthSales.HasValue) && (monthSales.Value > 0))
    {
        DataTable destTable= dsproduct.Tables["MainTable"];
        DataRow[] selectedRows = destTable.Select(salesExpression);
        DataRow destRow;
        if (selectedRows.Length > 1)
            throw new Exception(String.Format("MainTable has ProductID {0} duplicate Sales RowID 1.", productID));
        else if (selectedRows.Length == 1)
            destRow = selectedRows[0];
        else
        {
            destRow = destTable.NewRow();
            destRow.SetField<System.Int32>("RowID", 1);
            destRow.SetField<System.Int32>("ProductID", productID);
            destTable.Rows.Add(destRow);
        }

        string locColumn = "Loc" + r.Field<System.Char>("Loc");
        destRow.SetField<System.Int32>(locColumn, monthSales.Value);
    }
```

This should be fixed to avoid creating column names at runtime, and creating strongly-named DataTables would get rid of the `<System.Int32>` stuff, but this should get you started.